# Basic understanding of TCP

Tags: tcp, lifecycle

I don't fully understand when a TCP connection ends. That is, when a client sends a request to  a server and the server responds, is that response part of the same TCP connection? Or is that response made through a brand new TCP connection?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol Maybe you need documentation.. It is the same TCP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TCP connection ends when both sides have closed it. A response is sent over the same connection as the request, and there can be many request/response pairs over a single connection. Or none, just a download for example.